# postgresql backup and recovery

Tags: recovery, postgresql-9.2, backup

I’m trying to set up backup strategy for a production postgreSQL DB.
It will have large amount of data and it should be running 24 X 7.
Could you recommend some backup & recovery strategies that can meet the following criteria?

- Large amount data (about over 200GB).
- Hot backup (online backup)
- Minimum Impact on the DB performance.
- Minimum restore time.
- Allow PITR(Point-In-Time Recovery)

  1. Can we execute backup with above criteria on slave server of replication?
  2. If you know backup strategy using storage snapshot, Could you let me know?

Comment: the usual setup is (if I'm not mistaken) to create a slave using streaming replication and then to the backups on the slave (to minimize impact on the master). You might want to look at [pgBarman](http://www.pgbarman.org/) and [repmgr](http://repmgr.org/)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd be best suited by using a physical base backup + WAL archiving, with regularly updated snapshots of the base backup. I strongly recommend taking regular dumps anyway.

Using newer PostgreSQL versions (9.2 and up, IIRC) you can take fresh base backups from a replica server so you don't have to disrupt the master.

File-system or logical volume level snapshot backups work fine with PostgreSQL so long as your snapshots are *atomic*. Restoring one is like starting PostgreSQL back up after unexpected power loss or OS reboot, not a big deal.

See also:

- [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html)
- [A blog entry I wrote on this topic](http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/10/avoiding-postgresql-database-corruption.html)
- [Postgres Backup queries on AWS after reading Postgres docs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29674/7788)
- [PostgreSQL: Can I do pg_start_backup() on a live, running db under load?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30609/7788)
- [PostgreSQL "freeze"/"unfreeze" command equivalents](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44260/7788)
- [How to do incremental backup every hour in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/45870/7788)
- [Running pg_dump on a hot standby server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30626/7788)
- [PostgreSQL crash recovery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/22799/7788)